# how to deploy R Shiny app on Azure App Services with Azure Active Directory Integration

Tags: r, shiny, azure-web-app-service, shinydashboard, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm using Microsoft azure service, In azure machine learning I'm using R Studio to create shiny web application. Everything works fine. But I want to deploy R Shiny app in Azure App services with the help of Azure Active Directory Authentication

What is the process to deploy R Shiny app in Azure App services?

Answer (score 0):

There is a product called "RStudio Connect" which is RStudio's application server for Shiny apps. It can be deployed to Azure using via [this Marketplace image](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/rstudio-5237862.rstudio-connect?tab=PlansAndPrice&exp=ubp8). It is, however, quite costly and I am unsure of the AAD tie-in.